# Rearrange sequence of userform controls

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I created this userform in excel, however, I realized that when I hit 'tab' on the keyboard to go to the next field, it goes in a jumbled-up sequence as presented in the screenshot.

I wonder if there's a way to reset this sequence so that it goes smoothly from left to right (client name, base pay, and so on.) then move over to the checkboxes area?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: That's the `TabIndex` value in the properties of the control. You will need to go one by one through the controls in the order you want. So for the first item you use value 0, then 1, then 2 etc. I don't believe there is a way to automatically go through the controls, I think you have to do it manually. Once you set it though, it will stay. The reason it's jumbled is because the tab order is defined by the order the controls were created.

Answer (score 1):

**a) Reset tab indices via VBA**

Assuming textboxes named e.g. "TextBox1", "TextBox2" etc. thus indicating the wanted order
you might code as follows:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim no As Long
    For no = 1 To 5                    ' corresponding to tab indices 0..4
        With Me.Controls.Item("TextBox" & no)
            .TabIndex = no - 1
        End With
    Next
    ''optional continuation with Frame1 (checkbox container)
    ' Me.Controls.Item("Frame1").TabIndex = no - 1
End Sub
```

Note that TextBox1 as *number one control* will get focus with a zero-based `.TabIndex` property of `0`.
The dynamically changed tab indices will shift any other already existing indices
following the order they were created.

**Alternative loop**

Of course it's also possible to loop through an *array* holding the control objects by:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ctrls
    ctrls = Array(TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(ctrls) To UBound(ctrls)
        ctrls(i).TabIndex = i
    Next
    ''optional continuation with Frame1 (checkbox container)
    'Me.Controls.Item("Frame1").TabIndex = i
End Sub
```

This would allow to use any other naming convention for your textboxes, like e.g. `ctrls = Array(ClientName, BasePay, ...)`.

**b) Smart change tab orders (manually)**

Though tab behaviour changed dynamically is executed correctly now, the existing *hard* tab indices in *designer* won't be changed by the above procedures.
This is unsatifying, especially if you want to check the tabs in the VB Editor's properties window.

Personally I'd prefer to make a manual change by

- right clicking directly into the Userform in designer mode and
- choosing "Activation order" in the context menu

or by a **quick change** selecting the whole starter group by

- selecting the first textbox (click) and the following textboxes (Ctrl+Click) in the wanted order
- and entering only `0` as (starting) tabindex.

instead of manipulating the *designer* programatically (e.g. using libraray reference `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3`).